# powershell command to disable combination keys in windows registry

Tags: java

Is there any commands to disable below combination keys without reboot of system to use in java swing application(in jframe full screen) :
1.Alt and tab pressed at same time.
2.Disable notification from 3rd party application like outlook mail etc.
3.Disable Alt+space showing certain tabs.

Note:need commands that suit windows 7,8,10 versions

Comment: As far as I am aware, can only be done using Windows API. You can use JNA (Java Native Access) to simplify calling Windows API functions from java. So maybe you should tag your question ___winapi___

Comment: Do a web search for "kiosk mode". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app came up for me.